# Local branches pulling from one place and pushing to two different remotes and in different branches(names)

Tags: git, github, gitorious

Lets say I have 2 unrelated projects (Talking about git), but due to my inconsistency I switch between them frequently. Both have a 'master' and a 'trunk' branch (and are both located at different hosting sites (github and gitorious) is it possible to created a 3-rd repository containing only the content of the trunk branches of those two under a different branch names?
e.g.:... I though visualizing it would be more descriptive so:[Image](http://ft.trillian.im/90f2ee22002772b8fb28659fd37a23b4fae66fa9/6bl1ZGKspEmJobwFv9jEm9ez7E9YC.jpg)

In the end my question is what commands should I enter to be able to push from all the projects and the changes to be applied automatically (--mirror I'm guessing but after 1 day of reading left and right that's as far as I got)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use `git remote add` to add each of your two repositories to a git archive (an empty one  is probably sanest) and give them different names ("github" and "gitorious" seem sane).  The after fetching each one, you will see their branches as "/remotes/{github,gitorious}/trunk" (or master, etc..) and can operate on them using git as you like -- e.g. cherry pick commits between branches, merge branches, get a log of differences, find the merge-base, etc...

Comment: awesome tip! I would just add that in  order to have it fully operational OP would have to create local tracking branches like that: git branch project1 github/trunk; git branch project2 gitorious/trunk

Comment: now that someone else summarized it for me it's quite clearer than my own image of how it should be done. Still I want to be able to do `cd ./Project3/` then `git checkout project2` and then `git push/pull` (with no additional info) is `git branch --set-upstream project1 trunk` the command I should use for that?

Comment: That is exactly what Andy provided: $ cd Project3; git init; git remote add project1 {github/project}; git remote add project2 {gitorious/project}; git fetch --all; git branch project1 project1/trunk; git branch project2 project2/trunk ---- when you are explicitely specifying a remote branch from which you're creating local branch using "branch" command it will automatically create tracking branch, the same way as the --set-upstream does.

Comment: I still wanna be able to do it without specifying where to push/pull from every time, just a genuine `git push/pull`

Comment: Just push with a `-u` argument the first time  and it will automatically set up the tracking branch for you so you don't need to specify it again.  Setting up remote tracking branches for local branches is an orthogonal problem to having local branches cloned from multiple remote repositories.